# Mediaelement.js not setting width and height until clicked

Tags: java, javascript, mediaelement.js

We've been successfully using `mediaelement.js` for video on a number of projects. Yesterday we noticed that `IE8` was failing, so we updated to the latest `Mediaelement.js` version (2.16.3).

This solved the original `IE8` issue, but now all videos fail to set a height or width on the video element and also the `.mejs-container` div in `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `IE8`.

All you see when the page loads, is the control bar and the main button icon.

When you click `Play`, the height and width are set, and everything works fine. There are no `JS` errors, and the same code works perfectly outside of the `CMS (Pirobase)`.

Any ideas? I'm getting a little frustrated.

Comment: Pirobase is a Java CMS... I wasn't allowed to create the Pirobase tag.

Comment: OK, I'll retract my comment. Thanks for the information.